# Exception setcurrentcelladdresscore thrown changing rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to replicate this behavior in the ColumnMappings window from SQL Management Studio:
[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaA36.png)

> When you click inside a destination cell, the type changes from text
> to combobox (it seems), and when you leave the cell, it takes the selected value from the combobox and changes back to textboxCell with the value included.

It does this for every cell in that column.
So, when I load the data, all the cells are textbox, and when the user enters any cell in that column, I do this:

```
private void dgvwMapping_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            
            string txt = dgvwMapping[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbbxDestination = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell() { DataSource = new List<string>(someList) };
            cbbxDestination.Value = txt;
            dgvwMapping[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] = cbbxDestination;
        }
    }
```

So far so good, if I change from cell to cell everything goes fine, except when I click the cell that has the coordinates [1,1]. The only one that throws the "Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore" exception is the one with the columnIndex equal to the rowIndex.

I already tried wrapping the line where I reassign the Cell Type in an invoke call, like this:

```
dgvwMapping.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
{
         dgvwMapping[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] = cbbxDestination;
}));
```

But It loops indefinitely the event. Even wrapping all the code inside the event makes the event loop indefinitely.
I haven't coded anything inside the CellEndEdit or the CellLeave yet.

Does anyone have any advice? Perhaps my aproach at replicating that behavior is not the best.

Thanks

Comment: Don't change it.  Use the DisplayStyle set to DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing

Comment: if you mean changing:

DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbbxDestination = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell() { DataSource = new List<string>(someList) };
to:

DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbbxDestination = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell() { DataSource = new List<string>(someList), DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing };

I tried, but the same happens.

Comment: No, I mean get rid of all that stuff in the CellEnter event and just set the grid's ComboBox style.

Comment: That's it. I was choosing the hardest path. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue:

> When you click inside a destination cell, the type changes from text to combobox (it seems), and when you leave the cell, it takes the selected value from the combobox and changes back to textboxCell with the value included.

is just a simple style setting for the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn property:

```
yourGridColumnComboBox.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
```

This will make it appear like a TextBox, but when it has focus with selectable items, it will show the drop down button.